# JS - не работает append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не добавляет в `textarea` смайлы (точнее их текстовые обозначения), в чем проблема?

В js не силен, а методом научного тыка получается или смайлы отправить, но текст не отправляется, или наоборот.

В шапке подключен jquery-1.7.1.js

```
<textarea class="textarea"> </textarea> <!---  name="textarea" contentEditable="true" --->
<input class="btnWrite" type="submit" value="TO SEND"> 

<div class="smail">
    <div class="smail_block">
     <li><img src="img/smiles/1.gif"  onClick="javascript: $('.textarea').append('::1::');" /></li>
     <li> ------------------- еще 18 смайлов ---------------- </li>
     <li><img src="img/smiles/20.gif" onClick="javascript: $('.textarea').append('::20::');" /></li>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
 //Отправка сообщений----------------------------------------------------------------------
 function WriteMesseg(){
     //передаем текст из поля textarea в переменную textarea
     //var textarea = $('.textarea').val(); 
     var textarea = $('.textarea').val(); //.text()
     //записываем в скрытый див для передачи
     $("#messedg").html(textarea);


     //очищаем textarea
    // $('.textarea').val('');//.html(" ");   .empty();  .clear() .text('')  .val('')
       $('.textarea').val('');
     // $('.textarea').text('');
     // $('.textarea').empty();
     // $('.textarea').clear();

    }
    //выполнение функции WriteMesseg по нажатию кнопки с классом .btn_go
    $(document).on('click', '.btnWrite',WriteMesseg);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Если захочется визуальности, делаем див с contenteditable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 onClick="javascript: $('.textarea').val($('.textarea').val()+'::1::')"
```

**[посмотреть, как работает](https://jsfiddle.net/rkujds5h/)**

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо, я 3 дня танцевал с бубном. К сожалению моя репутация не позволяет выразить мою благодарность. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы можете принять ответ. А остальное уж ладно, когда подрастете :) Удачи!

Comment: Плюсую от Романа. @Роман, если не уйдёте с сайта, репутация подрастёт точно.

Comment: @Other вроде бы уже достаточно подросла )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, на момент написания - нет, сейчас уже может быть, но плюс не уберу, я добрый :)

Answer (score -1):

```
onClick = "javascript: $('.textarea').val($('.textarea').val()+'::1::')"
```

Лучше использовать `$(this)` вместо `$('.textarea')`, так как `'.textarea'` будет выбирать все текстовые поля с классом "textarea" на странице.

Comment: Такие вещи лучше писать в комментарии к ответу или оформлять их как полноценный ответ.

Comment: Это уточнение к ответу splash58?

Comment: Nick Volynkin, да это уточнее к его комментарию. к сожалению я не могу написать комментарий к его ответу. Но я не мог не заметить что его ответ содержит потенциальный баг.